# Get lowest & highest date values from datatables selected rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a situation where I need to find the lowest and highest values of dates (format: 'YYYY-MM-DD') from datatables selected rows on a button click.
I managed to get sum of values from another column called 'Total', but struggling how to calculate smallest and largest date value.
My code is:

```
// Show data in alert:
// for example: From 2016-06-02 to 2016-06-05: Total = xxxxx.xx
$('#showData').click(function() {
  var totalSUM = 0;
  $("table tbody tr.selected").each(function() {
    var getTotal = $(this).find("td:eq(1)").html();
    totalSUM += Number(getTotal);
  });
  alert('From "fromDate" to "toDate": Total = ' + totalSUM);
});
```

> And here is the working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sohal/853n3q4L/)

Comment: Put all the dates into an array, sort the array, get first and last element.

Comment: You don't need to sort entire array to get min and max values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also keep track of minDate and maxDate and update them on each iteration just as you're already doing with totalSUM.

```
$('#showData').click(function() {
  var totalSUM = 0, minDate, maxDate;
  $("table tbody tr.selected").each(function() {
    var getTotal = $(this).find("td:eq(1)").text(),
        date = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text();
    totalSUM += Number(getTotal);
    minDate = !minDate || date < minDate ? date : minDate;
    maxDate = !maxDate || date > maxDate ? date : maxDate;
  });
  alert('From "fromDate" to "toDate": Total = ' + totalSUM + ' from ' + minDate + ' to ' + maxDate);
});
```

[Forked Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dv9mq4cd/2/)

Comment: thanks Arnauld: for ur help, i have forked the fiddle again to solve another issue, i'm sure its not a big problem for u. Link is: https://jsfiddle.net/sohal/v1xjrvym/1/

Comment: @sohal07: see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8Ls1xgcb/) for a test on consecutive days

Answer (score 1):

Pick min and max value while looping over selected rows. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/fv38L4na/1/).

```
  var totalSUM = 0, minDate, maxDate;
  $("table tbody tr.selected").each(function() {
    var getTotal = $(this).find("td:eq(1)").html(),
        date = new Date($(this).find('td:eq(0)').text());

     if(!minDate || minDate > date) minDate = date;
     if(!maxDate || maxDate < date) maxDate = date;

    totalSUM += Number(getTotal);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can create a new array of all the dates, `sort()` it, then use `pop()` and `shift()` to get the newest and oldest dates. Try this:

```
$('#showData').click(function() {
    var totalSUM = 0;
    var dates = $("table tbody tr.selected").map(function() {
        totalSUM += parseFloat($(this).find("td:eq(1)").text());
        return new Date($(this).find('td:eq(0)').text());
    }).get().sort(function(a, b) { return b - a; });    
    var oldestDate = dates.pop();
    var newestDate = dates.shift();

    console.log(oldestDate);
    console.log(newestDate);
    console.log('From "fromDate" to "toDate": Total = ' + totalSUM);
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/853n3q4L/11/)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in comment- make array, sort it, get first and last element:

```
// Show data in alert:
// for example: From 2016-06-02 to 2016-06-05: Total = xxxxx.xx
$('#showData').click(function() {
  var totalSUM = 0,
      dateArray = new Array();
  $("table tbody tr.selected").each(function() {
    var getTotal = $(this).find("td:eq(1)").html(),
        currDate =  new Date($(this).find("td:eq(0)").html());
    totalSUM += Number(getTotal);
    dateArray.push(currDate.getTime());
  });
  dateArray.sort();
  var fromDate = new Date(dateArray[0]);
  var toDate = new Date(dateArray[dateArray.length-1]);
  alert('From '+fromDate.toLocaleDateString()+' to '+toDate.toLocaleDateString()+': Total = ' + totalSUM);
});
```